# RSS not working in major browsers

Tags: xml, rss, atom-feed

Need to know whether my rss feed xml code is correct or not. It was working properly and I was able to get the live feed from major browsers. But not able to see this works now. I was using a atom rss feed xml code.

Rss feed link: http://www.amicorp.com/rss.xml

Please check and help me.

Comment: http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=feed%3A%2F%2Fwww.amicorp.com%2Frss.xml

Comment: Thanks it works! Now I have updated all the feed into the code and it was used fully. But only able to view the latest one in live feed. but the older ones not showing. Please suggest.